# pytest: get parametrize values during setup/teardown method

Tags: python, automation, pytest, nose

My automation framework uses pytest setup/teardown type of testing instead of fixtures. I also have several levels of classes:

`BaseClass` - highest, all tests inhriet from it

`FeatureClass` - medium, all tests related to the programs feature inherit from it

`TestClass` - hold the actual tests

**edit, for examples sake, i change the DB calls to a simple print**

I want to add DB report in all setup/teardowns. i.e. i want that the general `BaseClass` `setup_method` will create a DB entry for the test and `teardown_method` will alter the entry with the results. i have tried but i can't seem to get out of method the values of currently running test during run time. is it possible even? and if not, how could i do it otherwise?

samples:
(in base.py)

```
class Base(object):

    test_number = 0
    def setup_method(self, method):
        Base.test_number += 1
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("STARTING TEST"))
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("Current Test: {}".format(method.__name__)))
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("Test Number: {}".format(self.test_number)))
        # --->here i'd like to do something with the actual test parameters<---
        self.logger.info("print parameters here")

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("Current Test: {}".format(method.__name__)))
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("Test Number: {}".format(self.test_number)))
        self.logger.info(color.Blue("END OF TEST"))
```

(in my_feature.py)

```
class MyFeature(base.Base):

    def setup_method(self, method):
        # enable this feature in program
        return True
```

(in test_my_feature.py)

```
class TestClass(my_feature.MyFeature):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("fragment_length", [1,5,10])    
    def test_my_first_test(self):
        # do stuff that is changed based on fragment_length
        assert verify_stuff(fragment_length)
```

so how can i get the parameters in setup_method, of the basic parent class of the testing framework?

Comment: Are you using `unittest.TestCase`? Then you can set the values in `setup` to `self` and retrieve it in the tests. More details like a sample code is needed to answer this question.

Comment: @Arunmozhi i've added some basic code, hope it will clarify what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brief answer: NO, you cannot do this. And YES, you can work around it.

---

A bit longer: these unittest-style setups & teardowns are done only for compatibility with the unittest-style tests. They do not support the pytest's fixture, which make pytest nice.

Due to this, neither pytest nor pytest's unittest plugin provide the context for these setup/teardown methods. If you would have a `request`, `function` or some other contextual objects, you could get the fixture's values dynamically via `request.getfuncargvalue('my_fixture_name')`.

However, all you have is `self`/`cls`, and `method` as the test method object itself (i.e. not the pytest's node).

If you look inside of the `_pytest/unittest.py` plugin, you will find this code:

```
class TestCaseFunction(Function):
    _excinfo = None

    def setup(self):
        self._testcase = self.parent.obj(self.name)
        self._fix_unittest_skip_decorator()
        self._obj = getattr(self._testcase, self.name)
        if hasattr(self._testcase, 'setup_method'):
            self._testcase.setup_method(self._obj)
        if hasattr(self, "_request"):
            self._request._fillfixtures()
```

First, note that the `setup_method()` is called fully isolated from the pytest's object (e.g. `self` as the test node).

Second, note that the fixtures are prepared after the `setup_method()` is called. So even if you could access them, they will not be ready.

So, generally, you cannot do this without some trickery.

---

For the trickery, you have to define a pytest hook/hookwrapper once, and remember the pytest node being executed:

`conftest.py` or any other plugin:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
    item.cls._item = item
    yield
```

`test_me.py`:

```
import pytest


class Base(object):
    def setup_method(self, method):
        length = self._item.callspec.getparam('fragment_length')
        print(length)


class MyFeature(Base):
    def setup_method(self, method):
        super().setup_method(method)


class TestClass(MyFeature):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("fragment_length", [1,5,10])    
    def test_my_first_test(self, fragment_length):
        # do stuff that is changed based on fragment_length
        assert True  # verify_stuff(fragment_length)
```

Also note that `MyFeature.setup_method()` must call the parent's `super(...).setup_method()` for obvious reasons.

The `cls._item` will be set on each callspec (i.e. each function call with each parameter). You can also put the item or the specific parameters into some other global state, if you wish.

Also be carefull not to save the field in the `item.instance`. The instance of the class will be created later, and you have to use `setup_instance/teardown_instance` method for that. Otherwise, the saved instance's field is not preserved and is not available as `self._item` in `setup_method()`.

Here is the execution:

```
============ test session starts ============
......
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                 

test_me.py::TestClass::test_my_first_test[1] 1
PASSED
test_me.py::TestClass::test_my_first_test[5] 5
PASSED
test_me.py::TestClass::test_my_first_test[10] 10
PASSED

============ 3 passed in 0.04 seconds ============
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, it really helped me understand pytest better. i'm going to try and implement this. i see you explicitly used 'fragment_length' to get it's value, so if i want to get all of the parameters a certain test have i would need to get self._item.callspec.params and iterate over its values?

Comment: @AvishayCohen I cannot say for sure, but most likely yes. All the fields and methods here are part of the pytest's advanced api. The only problem was that the item/node/callspec are not exposed to the unittest's classes/methods. I think, that was intentional for backward compatibility with unittest, and is not supposed for the normal pytest usage.